# Overriding the default admin site - can't find myproject

Tags: django, django-admin, admin

I am trying to override the default admin site. I followed the Django Docs here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site

I did everything as stated there so the files look like beneath:

admin/admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _, gettext_lazy

class CustomAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    # Text to put in each page's <h1>.
    site_header = gettext_lazy('TEST administration')
```

admin/apps.py

```
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig

class CustomAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'admin.CustomAdminSite'
```

core/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'testadmin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

core/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'admin.apps.CustomAdminConfig',
]
```

Now I am getting a ImportError:

*ImportError: Module "admin" does not define a "CustomAdminSite" attribute/class*

I think this is because django is looking for a admin module that lives inside of the virtual environment with the CustomAdminSite class. This is not the case, the admin folder with the necessary python files lives in the base path of myproject. When I state this in my settings like: myproject.admin.apps.CustomAdminConfig I am getting a ModuleNotFOundError:

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'*

I guess the same thing as stated above. Django is looking for a module named myproject inside of the virtual environment.

Is there a way to change this in the settings or a way to bypass this some other way?

Comment: Should it not be “admin.admin.CustomAdminSite”?

Comment: Good one! Changed this in the apps.py. Now it says: No module named apps.urls.

Answer (score 0):

As [@IainShelvington said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63254500/overriding-the-default-admin-site-cant-find-myproject#comment111855242_63254500), the name of the module is likely `admin.admin`, since `admin` is the name of the app, and then in that app you have a "submodule" named `admin`, so this should be:

```
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig


class CustomAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'admin.admin.CustomAdminSite'
```